# Towel dedusting it- what is the VERB for it?

Tags: verbs

I can't get the word out on when you are "**dedusting**" a towel. It's like there is dust on it, and you abruptly "**flap**" the farthest side from you while holding the two near ends of the towel.

> What is the **verb** for it?

Answer (score 3):

So, let's say you use the towel to *wipe up* some (dry) dirt, and now you've got a full towel which you are holding carefully to keep the dirt from *spilling out*.  You're asking what you should then do with the towel?  *Shake it out*:

> Take the towel outside and **shake** it **out**.
>
> Hold the towel over the dustbin (BrE) / trash can (AmE) and **shake** the dirt **out** of it.

Of course, this won't work very well if you're talking about *wet* dirt or something sticky like that.  Instead you'll have to *wash out* the towel in the sink.

Comment: I see, so there is no verb for it, just a description. Thx anyway.

Comment: @JohnArvin **Shake out** is a verb. So is **wash out**. Its a good idea to memorize phrasal verbs like you would any other vocabulary, to understand the difference in meaning and usage between this form and other phrasal verbs like *shake up*

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker there isn't necessarily a word that comes to mind. I know what you're talking about but I can't think of any word for it. When a towel has water in it and you twist it out it is called "wring" (pronounced ringing), but that wouldn't make sense for dusting. "Whipping" is the closest thing I can think of. "Whipping a towel" makes sense but I'm not sure if that's the word you're looking for.

Kind of a pointless response but I tried.

Comment: *Wring* is pronounced *ring*; and *wringing* is pronounced *ringing* . . .